# Auto capitalize input field on BlackBerry

Tags: forms, html, blackberry, input

I have a HTML input (for data such as first name) on a website, and the client would like the field to auto capitalize. Do any weird attributes exist to enable such functionality on BlackBerry?

Comment: Why not just do it at the server?

Comment: The client has specifically asked the data to capitalize live on the client-side. Ended up using `text-transform: capitalize` on the input which was good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-transform: capitalize` in the CSS :)